# Настройка публикации файлов в зависимости от конфигурации

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, msbuild

Нужно чтобы при билде и публикации в результирующий каталог какие-то файлы попадали, а какие-то нет в зависимости от конфигурации. Пробовал делать так, но не работает:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <Content Update="data.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Content Update="data.Production.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Также пробовал через post-build event удалять лишние файлы, но при публикации build-event'ы не отрабатывают.

Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: _не работает_ - что именно происходит: оба файла копируются или ни один не копируется?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, оба файла копируются

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вроде работает, как вам необходимо:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <Content Include="data.Development.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Content Include="data.Production.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Получаю ошибку: 

Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. The duplicate items were: ' 'data.Development.json';